# Feature and scenario outline name in cucumber before hook

Tags: cucumber

If I have a simple cucumber *feature* and *scenario*, like this (example code is from [cucumber wiki](https://github.com/cucumber/cucumber/wiki/Scenario-outlines)):

```
Feature: Eating cucumbers

Scenario: eat 5 out of 12
  Given there are 12 cucumbers
  When I eat 5 cucumbers
  Then I should have 7 cucumbers
```

I know how to get *feature* and *scenario* name in `before` hook:

```
Before do |scenario|
  p [scenario.feature.name, scenario.name]
end
```

The above code returns:

```
["Eating cucumbers", "eat 5 out of 12"]
```

The problem is if the *feature* has *scenario outline*:

```
Scenario Outline: eating
  Given there are <start> cucumbers
  When I eat <eat> cucumbers
  Then I should have <left> cucumbers

  Examples:
    | start | eat | left |
    |  12   |  5  |  7   |
```

When I run the above code I get:

```
undefined method `feature' for #<Cucumber::Ast::OutlineTable::ExampleRow:0x007fb0f94a8240> (NoMethodError)
```

How do I get *feature* and *scenario outline* name in cucumber `before` hook?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Change `before` hook to this:

```
Before do |scenario|
  p [scenario.scenario_outline.feature.name, scenario.scenario_outline.name, scenario.name]
end
```

Output:

```
["Eating cucumbers", "eating", "| 12 | 5 | 7 |"]
```

Comment: scenario.feature is removed in cucumber 1.2.4 - I haven't yet found another way to get at the feature.name

Answer (score 0):

scenario.gets should give you feature name.

Comment: This answer is a stub and should rather be a [comment](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment). Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to comment. If you don't have enough reputation, read [this post](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead) on how to contribute if you don't have enough reputation yet.